# standard language and notation for comparing two normal distributions

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Say I have two normal distributions that I'd like to compare in some writing: distribution A with mean = 12, standard deviation of 0.9; and distribution B with mean = 10, standard deviation of 1.1. I would like to describe how far apart these distributions are from each other in a modestly accurate but simple sense.  The means are 2 units (12-10) apart. The average standard deviation is 1 ((0.9 + 1.1)/2).  Is it reasonable in a simple sense to say "the means are 2 average standard deviations apart?" What would be a standard way of saying this in equation form with standard variable conventions? I'd guess it would be something like "nasa = 2." Here I'm using "nasa" for number of average standard deviations apart, because I have no idea what symbol to use.

Comment: There are many ways to compare two probability distributions: e.g. given the two distributions you can compute their `distance' from eachother using Kullback-Leibler Divergence, Total Variation, Wasserstein Distance, $L_1$ norm, etc.

Since you have two normal distributions these will usually take explicit values. For instance in the Wasserstein case there is this blog post https://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2010/04/30/wasserstein-distance-between-two-gaussians/.